# org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters resource object will not hydrate/populate on extended operation

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have a custom IResourceProvider that serves Measure (Measure.class).

In that code, I have the following extended operation. (from http://hapifhir.io/doc_rest_operations.html#_toc_extended_operations )

```
@Operation(name = "$humptydumpty")
public org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Bundle acceptHumptyDumpty(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                                                                  @IdParam(optional = true) IdType theId,
                                                                  @OperationParam(name = "request") org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Measure item) {
    String fakeMessage;

    if (null == item) {
        fakeMessage = "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Measure item is null.  Sad face.  :( ";
    } else {
        fakeMessage = "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Measure item is not null.  Happy face.  :) ";
    }


    Bundle retVal = new Bundle();
    retVal.setId(fakeMessage);
    return retVal;
}
```

If I pass in the example JSON from

http://hl7.org/fhir/STU3/measure-exclusive-breastfeeding.json.html

POST

> http://localhost:8080/fhir/Measure/MyMeasureName123/$humptydumpty

Everything works fine.  I get back.

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Measure item is not null.  Happy face.  :) "
}
```

So I understand the basics of how the $myExtendedMethod works.

NOW, when I try the same for .Parameters....

Java code (same MyResourceProvider as above)

```
@Operation(name = "$robinhood")
public Bundle acceptRobinHood(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                                         @IdParam(optional = true) IdType theId,
                                         @OperationParam(name = "request") org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters item) {

    String fakeMessage;

    if (null == item) {
        fakeMessage = "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters item is null.  Sad face.  :( ";
    } else {
        fakeMessage = "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters item is not null.  Happy face.  :) ";
    }


    Bundle retVal = new Bundle();
    retVal.setId(fakeMessage);
    return retVal;
}
```

POST

> http://localhost:8080/fhir/Measure/MyMeasureName123/$robinhood

I've sent in the "example" from http://hl7.org/fhir/STU3/parameters-example.json .

```
{
  "resourceType": "Parameters",
  "id": "example",
  "parameter": [
    {
      "name": "start",
      "valueDate": "2010-01-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "end",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Binary",
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "content": "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZXhhbXBsZQ=="
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And if I send in ... the most basic json.

```
{
  "resourceType": "Parameters",
  "id": "MyParameterId234"
}
```

I get the sad face. :(

I've tried everything.

The "item" is always null.  Aka, I get this back.

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters item is null.  Sad face.  :( "
}
```

I've tried many things, and finally went back to the ".Measure" just to prove I wasn't crazy.

But I cannot figure why one will populate (.Measure resource), and the other (.Parameters) will not.  #help

My hapi fhir version:

```
<properties>
    <hapi.version>3.6.0</hapi.version>
</properties>

    <!-- FHIR dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-structures-dstu3</artifactId>
        <version>${hapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-server</artifactId>
        <version>${hapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-base</artifactId>
        <version>${hapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-validation-resources-dstu3</artifactId>
        <version>${hapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

APPEND:

I did one for patient

```
@Operation(name = "$teddybear")
public org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Bundle acceptTeddyBear(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                                                          @IdParam(optional = true) IdType theId,
                                                          @OperationParam(name = "request") org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient item) {
    String fakeMessage;

    if (null == item) {
        fakeMessage = "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient item is null.  Sad face.  :( ";
    } else {
        fakeMessage = "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient item is not null.  Happy face.  :) ";
    }


    Bundle retVal = new Bundle();
    retVal.setId(fakeMessage);
    return retVal;
}
```

POST

http://localhost:8080/fhir/Measure/MyMeasureName123/$teddybear

> http://hl7.org/fhir/STU3/patient-example.json

and it works fine.

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Patient item is not null.  Happy face.  :) "
}
```

Its only the .Parameters resource that is hurting me.

APPEND

As per James A's answer and work around hint, I have put in the below.

Work Around Code: (aka, the "ANSWER" in the sense of a work around answer)

```
@Operation(name = "$robinhood")
public Bundle acceptRobinHood(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                              @IdParam(optional = true) IdType theId,
        /*@OperationParam(name = "request") org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters item*/ @ResourceParam String theRawBody) {
    String fakeMessage;

    if (null == theRawBody || StringUtils.isBlank(theRawBody)) {
        fakeMessage = "theRawBody is null or isBlank.  Sad face.  :( ";
    } else {
        fakeMessage = "theRawBody is not null and is not isBlank.  Happy face.  :) ";
    }

    org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters paramsObject = null;
    FhirContext ctx = FhirContext.forDstu3();//  this.getContext();  /* prefer encapsulated over hard coding, but for SOF, put in the hard code */
    IParser parser = ctx.newJsonParser();
    IBaseResource res = parser.parseResource(theRawBody);
    paramsObject = (org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters) res;
    if (null != paramsObject) {
        fakeMessage += " org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters was serialized from theRawBody.  Super Happy face.  :) :)";
    }
    else
    {
        fakeMessage += " org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters was NOT serialized from theRawBody (is null).  Super Sad face.  :( :( ";
    }

    Bundle retVal = new Bundle();
    retVal.setId(fakeMessage);
    return retVal;
}
```

and the response from execution of the code:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "theRawBody is not null and is not isBlank.  Happy face.  :)  org.hl7.fhir.dstu3.model.Parameters was serialized from theRawBody.  Super Happy face.  :) :)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this looks like a bug in HAPI FHIR. If you wanted to report it on the GitHub tracker that would be great.

You could probably work around it by adding a parameter along the lines of:

@ResourceParam String theRawBody

And using HAPI FHIR's parser to parse the Parameters resource. This is annoying for sure, but I believe it would work.

Comment: I have appended my question with the code that implements the work around.  So this answer... did answer my question.  I will report the bug.  Thanks for the quick feedback James.

Comment: Done : https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/issues/1230  Thanks again James.  #notBlockedNow